# replace specific chunk of string when string is path

Tags: python, python-3.x

hi I have a string like this:

```
path = "/level1/level2/level3/file.csv"
```

I want to do a operation in 2 steps like first is want to replace file name for example

```
path = "/level1/level2/level3/file_1.csv"
```

and in some cases only folder which is 2nd last from end like this

```
   path = "/level1/level2/level3_1/file.csv"
```

so what will be best way to do this ?
currently I am doing like this

```
path.replace('level3','level3_1')
```

but It got failed when there is same name exist somewhere else in string ...

Comment: Split the string on `/`. Replace. Join back.

Comment: Or use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html) to avoid errors with `replace()` when 2 same directories are in path.

##### File

```py
import re

path = "/level1/level2/level3/file.csv"

# get file
file = re.search("[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+", path).group(0).split(".")
file_name = file[0]
file_type = file[1]
new_path = path.replace(f"{file_name}.{file_type}", "file_2.txt")

print(new_path)
```

Output

```
/level1/level2/level3/file_2.txt
```

##### Last folder

```
import re

path = "/level1/level2/level3/file.csv"

# search for file
file = re.search("[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+", path).group(0)

# to make sure it's last folder, get it with the file
level3_folder = re.search(f"[A-Za-z0-9_ -]+/{file}", path).group(0)

# remove the file from folder to rename it
level3_folder = level3_folder.replace(f"/{file}", "")

# rename it
new_path = path.replace(f"{level3_folder}/{file}", f"level3_1/{file}")

print(new_path)
```

Output

```
/level1/level2/level3_1/file.csv
```

Comment: I updated it that it's independent of the file name and type.

Answer (score 0):

a different use of regexp could look like this:

```
from re import sub

path = "/level1/level2/level3/file.csv"

file_suff = '_1' # '' - for no replacement
dir_suff = '_1'  # '' - for no replacement

sub(r'(^.*)/(\w+)(\.\w+$)',fr'\1{dir_suff}/\2{file_suff}\3',path)

>>> out
'/level1/level2/level3_1/file_1.csv'
```